# Making apps for android 2.1 in flash cs5 via air. Impossible?

Tags: android, flash, air, adobe, android-2.0-eclair

Can anyone tell me if it is still posible to make applications for android 2.1 eclair in flash cs5 via air. I have spent a lot of time downloading, installing, configuring... all the nessesary software but when i try to install the apk on my android 2.1 device (htc desire wich i can't update to froyo because orange has still not released the update...) i get an error saying something alog the lines of "error_androidskd_outofdate" sorry i can't be more presice but i can't remember the exact words. I belive this is due to the fact that you can no longer put air apk files on android 2.1 despite the fact that i have allready installed the air runtime on the device.

Is it in fact inpossible? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Flash is only supported in >= 2.2. So no, you can't use flash in 2.1

Comment: Fairly sure. At least that was the tagline of 2.2, unless they backported flash to 2.1

Answer (score 0):

what you meen flash 10.1??
Because [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/how-to-install-flash-10-1-on-android-2-1-eclair-devices/) post says the oposit...

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the air version. Android 2.1 seems to support AIR 2.5. If you use the latest Air 2.6, it only runs on android 2.2. Now, the flash cs5.5 is released, it already integrates the air 2.6, and support android application deploy. Please check following post:

[Flash CS5.5 Android Development](http://android.jmsliu.com/277/flash-cs5-5-android-development.html)

[Air 2.6 System requirements](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/systemreqs/)